# Front end fails to represent correctly boxes

Tags: front-end, associations

**Context**

Sometimes my front end misrepresents some output typically involving associations. For instance

```
EmbedCode[CloudDeploy["hello, world"]]
```

should produce

[image]

according to the [documentation](https://www.wolfram.com/language/gallery/implement-hello-world-in-the-cloud/) but in fact yields

EmbeddingObject[Association[EnvironmentName->HTML,CodeSection->Association[Content->,Title->Automatic,Filename->cloudembed.html],CloudObject->CloudObject(https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2f2939a8-cd27-4c9a-99a2-c8ea44db36a6)]]

**Question**

> How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok it is a bit cheeky to answer one's own question but I stubbled on the solution months after wondering what was going wrong.

> The solution is to convert the output-cell into **standard** form (command shift N) rather than **traditional** form (my default).

I hope this can prove useful to others.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong to self-answer. This is a common gotcha with traditional form.

Comment: @b3m2a1 should we draw attention to WRI to this as some kind of (admittedly weak) bug?